# Issues with animating UI in different aspect ratio in unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, animation

I am struggling with animating the Unity UI. It's just a simple slide up menu I have animated via the anchored position. The problem comes when the aspect ratio is changed, it will often end up completely offscreen instead of stopping in the intended position.

Comment: You need to use relative coordinates or scale your UI movements by the screen size. The second option is often easier to implement. Design your UI for a certain size, then any animations coordinate values you can multiply by a scale factor for x/y by dividing the actual screen size by the planned for screen size on each axis. This gives you a scale factor, it's up to you if you want to scale your actual UI elements or just the positions.

Comment: The problem is you don't have used anchors properly. if you do that you should be fine. If you add some screenshots we can help you better.

Comment: @Charleh
how can I manipulate the animation values?